# Documented Cuke.JS doesn't seem to work

Tags: cucumberjs

I have the following code...

```
// support/world.js
/*jslint node: true */
"use strict";
var zombie = require('zombie');
var WorldConstructor = function WorldConstructor(callback) {
  this.browser = new zombie();
  var world = {
    visit: function(url, callback){
        this.browser.visit(url, callback);
    }
  };

  callback(world); // tell Cucumber we're finished and to use our world object instead of 'this'
};
exports.World = WorldConstructor;
```

---

```
// step_definition/note_steps.js
var noteStepDefinitionWrapper = function() {
    this.World = require("../support/world.js").World; // overwrite default
    // World constructor

    this.Given(/^I am on the main page$/, function(callback) {
        console.log("Step 1");
//      console.log(JSON.stringify(require("../support/world.js").World));
        this.visit('http://localhost:8080', callback);
    });

    this.When(/^I click the add button$/, function(callback) {
        console.log("Step 2")
        callback();
    });

    this.When(/^I fill out question information$/, function(callback) {
        console.log("Step 3")
        callback();
    });

    this.When(/^I click submit$/, function(callback) {
        console.log("Step 4")
        callback();
    });
    this.Then(/^I should see the new question$/, function(callback) {
        console.log("Step 5")
        callback();
    });
};
module.exports = noteStepDefinitionWrapper;
```

But when I try to run this I get the following...

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'visit' of undefined
  at Object.WorldConstructor.world.visit (***/grails-angular/src/test/features/support/world.js:8:18)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was related to [this jira issue](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/269). I would like to see some more ideas about this, do we really need to keep a monolithic world file?

```
var world = {
        visit : function(url, callback) {
              this.browser.visit(url);
              this.browser.wait(function() {
                    callback();
              });
        }.bind(this), //<-important
          ...
}
```